# Маршалинг типа char** в приложение C#

Tags: c#, c++

Имеется функция в dll, которая создает массив строк внутри себя и возвращает его + количеств элементов по указателю в аргументе(С++):

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)  char** GetListAdapters(int*);
```

Как мне импортировать эту функцию в приложении .NET C#? И, что самое важное, получить все значения массива строк?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Моя С++ функция:

```
char** WINAPI MyCppFunc(int * count)
{
    char** result = new char*[3];
    result[0] = "qwerty";
    result[1] = "1234567890";
    result[2] = "!";
    *count = 3;
    return result;
}
```

.NET импорт:

```
[DllImport("CppDll.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr MyCppFunc(ref int count);
```

И получение массива строк:

```
int count = 0;
IntPtr ptr = MyCppFunc(ref count);
string[] result = new string[count];
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    IntPtr charPtr = Marshal.ReadIntPtr(ptr + i * Marshal.SizeOf<IntPtr>());
    result[i] = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(charPtr);
}
```

Вам нужно будет узнать точное имя экспортируемой функции (в моем примере через def файл они совпадают), например, через утилиту `dumpbin`. Она идет вместе со студией.

Comment: Спасибо. Функция отработало, крахов не было, однако в массиве строк вернулся мусор. А вот количество аргументов верное. В чём может быть причина такого поведения?

Comment: У вас точно указатель на массив строк? Можете попробовать посмотреть, что вернет `Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(ptr)`.

Comment: Немножко подкрутил С++ - функцию, были неверные преобразования. Сейчас там точно массив строк, а *Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(ptr)* теперь возвращает пустую строку

Comment: Я не знаю, мой код делает 2 раза разыменование указателя, это и есть char**. Я проверил C# код вместе с C++. Скидывайте тогда свой C++.

Comment: Извиняюсь. Внимательно перепроверил код - писал в одну и ту же область памяти. Всё прекрасно работает. В догонку только: память ведь остаётся занятой? Её ведь следует очистить? Или gc от C# почистит её самостоятельно?

Comment: Память остаётся занятой, .net создаёт свои строки, которые не связаны с оригинальной памятью.

Comment: Ещё раз огромное спасибо!